# What is a purpose to provide a key when creating public widgets?

Tags: flutter

In `flutter_lints` the `use_key_in_widget_constructors` lint requres providing a key when creating public widgets.

> It's a good practice to expose the ability to provide a key when
> creating public widgets.

```
class MyPublicWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPublicWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
}
```

What is actualy the purpose of this lint rule i.e. what it gives?

Answer (score 2):

This is a convention. All widgets should allow specifying a key.
Your app won't suddenly stop working if a widget doesn't, but respecting that convention is a good thing.

It'd be inconvenient for users of a widget if they need to specify a key but that widget doesn't allow them to.

Answer (score 2):

As [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/22416843-unlocking-your-flutter-widgets-with-keys) article states:

1. Multiple widgets of the same type and at the same level in a widget tree may not update as expected unless they have unique keys, given that these widgets hold some state.
2. Explicitly setting a key to a widget helps Flutter understand which widget it needs to update when state changes.
3. Among other things, keys also store and restore the current scroll
   position in a list of widgets.